# Royalty Free Background Images For Android Application

Tags: android, image, resources

Does anyone know where I can get Royalty Free images (`Preferably High Quality`) for backgrounds? I need these for my Android App currently in development.

Comment: This question should probably go to http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nope, I don't think so, since it's related to development. I do believe that images/icons/drawables are essential part of development story.

Comment: My website http://www.ImageFree.com has a lot of free images that you could use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in [wikimedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org) - there're plenty of hi-res free images there

Answer (score 7):

[FreeImages.com (formerly stock.xchng)](http://www.freeimages.com/) is a great resource for Royalty Free images.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is not exactly what you want but [Subtle Patterns](http://subtlepatterns.com/) has some really nice textures (tiles) that can be repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Tried [istckphoto](http://www.istockphoto.com/)?